# how can i get the title, img and info when user click the product

Tags: javascript, html, dom

how can i get the title, img and info when user click the product so i insert the title and img and info from clicked product to product page template

```
//when click view more get title of eo.target 
const viewMore = document.getElementsByClassName("view-more")[0]
const getInfoFromClickedItem = () => {
    viewMore.addEventListener("click",(eo) => {
        const generateTitle = viewMore.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("card-title")[0]
        const insertTitle = document.getElementsByClassName("product-title")[0]
    }) 
}
```

the issue is when i click the button view more and go to product page i dont have access to main page and cant target html elements

Comment: paste your html code

Comment: this kind of code would means you have several product on the page and your eventlistener is on 1